# Solving an equation using Lambert function

Tags: lambert-w

Could anyone help me solve this equation in terms of $x$ using the Lambert $W$ function or even other methods:

$$x^{-a}e^{ - kx}
=c(n-x)^{-a}e^{ - k(n-x)}$$

Where $k$, $c$, and $n$ are constants, and $a$ is the path loss exponent of the system with a value (2.2), I am trying to change the frequency in order to have an integer $a$.

What I have tried is :
$$x^{-a}e^{ - kx}
=c(n-x)^{-a}e^{ - kn} e^{  kx}$$

Then, let $b=ce^{ - kn}$ and dividing both sides by  $e^{  kx}$,  we get:

$$x^{-a}e^{ -2 kx}
=b(n-x)^{-a}$$

I am stuck here afterward.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think Lambert $W$ will help, you will have to use numerical methods.

Comment: Are all variables positive?

Comment: @martycohen, yeah, all positive.

Comment: @elemelons, yeah maybe, but lets see if anyone can help solve it

Comment: Posting a question without knowing if it is solvable it's a bad practice, you should at least edit your question to give a warning.

Comment: @jjagmath, But I need to know if it's solvable or not!, that's why I asked for help here.

Comment: @HadeelObaid You can rearrange into $x=n-\sqrt[a]b x e^\frac{2kx}a$. There is a Lagrange reversion solution; for example, [this equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%3D0.2-+0.4%5E%281%2F0.8%29+%28x+e%5E%28%282+%280.3%29+x%29%2F0.8%29%29) has [this series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5B0.2%2Bsum%5B%28-+0.4%5E%281%2F0.8%29%29%5En%2Fn%21++D%5B%28x+e%5E%28%282+%280.3%29+x%29%2F0.8%29%29%5En%2C%7Bx%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C16%7D%5D%2Cx%3D0.2%5D). The derivatives have a confluent hypergeometric closed form. However, this method works better for $b<0$. Is this ok?

Comment: @TymaGaidash, I am not sure, let me see.

Comment: @TymaGaidash, thank you for your comment, but could you let me know why would I need that?

Comment: @HadeelObaid The “generalized Lambert function” in the below answer mentions its series expansions and, as it is a function from a research paper, is specialized, so it it likely not in Matlab by itself.

Comment: @TymaGaidash, okey then.

Comment: We should remove all our comments that are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{-a}e^{-kx}=c(n-x)^{-a}e^{-k(n-x)}$$

We see, this equation can be rearranged to a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

$$x^{-a}=ce^{-kn}(n-x)^{-a}e^{2kx}$$

$x\to \frac{1}{2k}t\ $ *:
$$\left(\frac{1}{2k}t\right)^{-a}=ce^{-kn}\left(n-\frac{1}{2k}t\right)^{-a}e^t$$
$$\frac{c\left(\frac{2kn-t}{2k}\right)^{-a}}{e^{kn}\left(\frac{1}{2k}t\right)^{-a}}e^t=1$$

for $a\neq 0$:
for $(a\in\mathbb{Q})\lor(k,n,t\in\mathbb{R})$:

$$\frac{c^\frac{1}{a}t}{e^\frac{kn}{a}(2kn-t)}e^\frac{t}{a}=1$$

$t\to au\ $ *:
$$\frac{ac^\frac{1}{a}u}{e^\frac{kn}{a}(2kn-au)}e^u=1$$
$$\frac{au}{2kn-au}e^u=c^{-\frac{1}{a}}e^{\frac{kn}{a}}$$
$$\frac{au}{au-2kn}e^u=-c^{-\frac{1}{a}}e^{\frac{kn}{a}}$$
$$\frac{u}{\frac{au-2kn}{a}}e^u=-c^{-\frac{1}{a}}e^{\frac{kn}{a}}$$
$$\frac{u}{u-\frac{2kn}{a}}e^u=-c^\frac{-1}{a}e^\frac{kn}{a}$$

We see, we cannot solve this equation in terms of Lambert W, but in terms of Generalized Lambert W.

$$u=W\left(^{\ \ 0}_\frac{2kn}{a};-c^\frac{-1}{a}e^\frac{kn}{a}\right)$$
$$t=aW\left(^{\ \ 0}_\frac{2kn}{a};-c^\frac{-1}{a}e^\frac{kn}{a}\right)$$
$$x=\frac{a}{2k}W\left(^{\ \ 0}_\frac{2kn}{a};-c^\frac{-1}{a}e^\frac{kn}{a}\right)$$

So we have [closed forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $x$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

*) *Because I don't want to use the transformation after equation (5) in [Mező/Baricz 2017] where I possibly would make mistakes, I want to transform the exponent of $e$ that contains $x$ to an exponent that is only a variable. Clearly you can proceed without this substitution.*
$\ $

[[Maignan/Scott 2016] Maignan, A.; Scott, T. C.: Fleshing out the Generalized Lambert W Function. ACM Communications in Computer Algebra 50 (2016) (2) 45-60](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307091430_Fleshing_out_the_generalized_Lambert_W_Function)

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply.......So if we are talking about the first part of your reply, if a=2.2, how can I further rearrangements of the equation?

Comment: @HadeelObaid I added that now. Could you please write your "$a$ is the path loss exponent of the system, I am trying to change the frequency in order to have an integer $a$" in your question? I could upvote your question then.

Comment: @ IV_, could you please let me know what function I can use in MATLAB for the Generalized Lambert W?

Comment: @HadeelObaid See the series representations in the references. | I haven't found yet computer algebra software that can work with Generalized Lambert W. I added [Maignan/Scott 2016] to my answer now.

Comment: We should remove all our comments that are no longer needed.